# crystal code programming erro

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

what is wrong with this formula

```
IF {@year2 number} = 2013 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 12' ELSE '- 13'
IF {@year2 number} = 2012 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 11' ELSE '- 12'
IF {@year2 number} = 2011 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 10' ELSE '- 11'
IF {@year2 number} = 2010 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 09' ELSE '- 10'
IF {@year2 number} = 2009 And {@Current Month}='Jan'THEN '- 08' ELSE '- 09'
IF {@year2 number} = 2008 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 07' ELSE '- 08'
IF {@year2 number} = 2007 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 06' ELSE '- 07'
IF {@year2 number} = 2006 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 05' ELSE '- 06'
IF {@year2 number} = 2005 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 04' ELSE '- 05'
IF {@year2 number} = 2004 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 03' ELSE '- 04'
IF {@year2 number} = 2003 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 02' ELSE '- 03'
IF {@year2 number} = 2002 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 01' ELSE '- 02'
IF {@year2 number} = 2001 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 00' ELSE '- 01'
IF {@year2 number} = 2000  And {@Current Month}='Jan'THEN '- 99' ELSE '- 00'
IF {@year2 number}= 1999 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 98' ELSE '- 99'
IF {@year2 number} = 1998 And {@Current Month}='Jan' THEN '- 97' ELSE '- 98'
```

Comment: Basically what i am trying to do is run the report with month and year parameter and i want to see ratings ( with month and year) for current month and last six months. So if i enter Jan 2012 it should display Jan-12, Dec-11, Nov-11, Oct-11, Sep-11 and so on or else if i enter nov-11 it should show Oct-11, Sep -11, Aug-11 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, user525552,

Relax. You can get rid of the formula entirely.  Drag & drop your date field onto your report design, then **right-click->format field->date and time** and pick your preferred display format.

### Edit

Based on your comment, try this formula. (I'm not convinced you actually need this formula, but this does answer your immediate question)

```
Monthname(
    month(
        DateAdd ("m", -4, {?Pm-Command.SCHED_END_DT})
    )
,true)

& "-" &

right(
    cstr(
        year(
            DateAdd ("m", -4, {?Pm-Command.SCHED_END_DT})
        )
    ,0,"")
,2)
```

Comment: But i am using formula to determine what date to dispaly, suppose i and searching for data for month of jan 2011, how will i see Jan-11, dec-10, nov-10 etc. How will it calculate 6 months criteria

Comment: i am deriving just month with the formula, can i derive month and year both ?  Month(DateAdd ("m", -4, {?Pm-Command.SCHED_END_DT}))

Comment: I have this formula to derive month  IF {@2nd Month Number} = 1 THEN 'Jan' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 2 THEN 'Feb' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 3 THEN 'Mar' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 4 THEN 'Apr' ELSE
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 5 THEN 'May' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 6 THEN 'Jun' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 7 THEN 'Jul' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 8 THEN 'Aug' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 9 THEN 'Sep' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 10 THEN 'Oct' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 11 THEN 'Nov' ELSE 
IF {@2nd Month Number} = 12 THEN 'Dec'

Comment: I have this formula to derive month IF {@2nd Month Number} = 1 THEN 'Jan' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 2 THEN 'Feb' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 3 THEN 'Mar' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 4 THEN 'Apr' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 5 THEN 'May' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 6 THEN 'Jun' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 7 THEN 'Jul' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 8 THEN 'Aug' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 9 THEN 'Sep' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 10 THEN 'Oct' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 11

Comment: THEN 'Nov' ELSE IF {@2nd Month Number} = 12 THEN 'Dec'                                      

Then I used your formula for 2nd Month Number                                                              But when i run it i get error string required here :- on this line {@2nd Month Number} = 1

Comment: How do i convert string to number in this,                        IF {@2nd Month Number} = 1 THEN 'Jan' ELSE

Comment: You can try replacing all that with this: `Monthname({@2nd Month Number},true)`. In general, I recommend you review your code and see how much of it is really necessary. You can probably replace much of it with built-in expressions. Good luck.

Comment: I am getting date and month in this format how do i get May-10  5.00-2,010.00   Month(DateAdd ("m", -4, {?Pm-Command.SCHED_END_DT})) & "-" & tonumber(Year(DateAdd ("m", -4, {?Pm-Command.SCHED_END_DT})))